# Ace editor enable emmet for twig mode

Tags: javascript, ace-editor, emmet

I'm using Ace Editor with `emmet` enabled. The following works fine, as expected:

```
var editor = ace.edit("editor");

editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/html");
editor.setOption("enableEmmet", true);
```

But if I change the mode to:

```
editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/twig");
```

It doesn't work anymore. Is there any way to make Emmet work in `ace/mode/twig`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `twig` to the regexp at https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.5/lib/ace/ext/emmet.js#L391

Comment: Not really the cleanest solution, but after looking over the source code there it seems to be the only way. Thanks!